# Jquery ui dialog not closing with `Escape` keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When a user opens dialog, there are a bunch of ajax requests that have to be processed and therefore i have a second dialog that just displays loading information and closes once all the requests have been processed.

I am not able to close the user opened dialog with Escape key once it has opened. I have to click on the the dialog itself before I can use escape.

I have tried the following to assign the user opened dialog the focus after the loading dialog closes but to no avail, I still have to click on the dialog before it can close with the escape key.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    // IF loading dialog is not allready being shown show it.
    if ($("#LoadingData").dialog('isOpen') === false) {
        $("#LoadingData").dialog('open');
    }
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    //Close the loading dialog once the requests have finished
    $("#LoadingData").dialog('close');
    //Find the user opened dialog
    $('.cmdialog').each(function () {
        if ($(this).dialog('isOpen')) {
            $(this).trigger('click');//set focus to dialog 
            // have also replaced .trigger('click') with .focus() but to no avail
        }
    }).on('click', function() {   
       //if click is triggerd set the focus of the dialog. 
        if ($(this).prop('id') != 'LoadingData') {
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
});
```

I have also tried setting the focus to the first element within the dialog with `$('#DialogName:first-child').focus()` and `$('#DialogName:first-child').trigger('click')` but this is also not working.

Any ideas as to why the focus is not set? Or am I misunderstanding/incorrectly using `.focus()` and `.trigger('event')`?

Thanks :)

Comment: Try this [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code for close the dialog when Escap key is pressed:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 27) { $("#LoadingData").dialog('close'); }   // esc
});
```

Comment: Hello thank you so much for you answer. This works but i have a follow up to this. Sometimes because of the nature of the page there are multiple dialogs that open on top of each other. This closes all of them and i only want to close the last opened one. How can i accomplish this. should i decale a page variable that stores the last opened dialog?

Comment: Ended up building an array that contain the id`s of the opened dialog and from there removing them in order from last to first added.

Comment: r u referring to the same dialog box with id LoadingData.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and found pretty elegant solution, in case you want to close dialog before actually clicking inside it:

```
$("#LoadingData").dialog({
   ...,
   focus: function () {
      $('#LoadingData').closest('.ui-dialog').focus();
   }
});
```

So, we just need to set focus to parent `.ui-dialog` container, and in that case <kbd>Esc</kbd> will work for all cases. Disadvantage of `$(document).keyup` solution, if you have nested dialogs, <kbd>Esc</kbd> button will close your most top dialog and bottom one too.

Answer (score 0):

the focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form elements (, , etc.) and links. [docs here](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

You can try moveToTop method of the dialog, maybe it will help

And in your code, I think, you should bind "click" event before triggering it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work even for multiple modals open:

```
        $(document).on('keydown','.modal-dialog',function(event){
            if (event.keyCode == 27) { 
                $(this).closest('.modal-dialog').find('[data-dismiss="modal"]').click();
            }
        });
```